# App keep crashing with java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

My app is keep crashinng after the splash actvity. In the error section it is showing `NullPointerException`. How to resolve this?

as suggest in error my `RecipeListFragment.java` file is:

```
public class RecipeListFragment extends Fragment {
MyDatabase db;
boolean isfav = false;
Context context;
ListView lvrecipe;
ArrayList<RecipePojo> recipelist = new ArrayList<RecipePojo>();
//  private MoPubView adView;
LinearLayout ll;
DisplayImageOptions options;
private ProgressDialog progress;
int position;
String recipeid;
int checkcounter = 0;

private Custom_Adapter adapter;

public RecipeListFragment() {

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recipe_list_actvity, container, false);
    context = getActivity();

    lvrecipe = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvrecipe);
    //  adView = (MoPubView)rootView. findViewById(R.id.mopub_sample_ad);

    new getrecipe().execute();


    db = new MyDatabase(getActivity());


    //  recipelist = DataManager.recipelist;
    position = DataManager.selectedposition;
    adapter = new Custom_Adapter(getActivity());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lvrecipe.setAdapter(adapter);


    lvrecipe.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            DataManager.selectedposition = position;
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), RecipeDescription.class);
            i.putExtra("cusinename", DataManager.cusinename);
            startActivity(i);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    //  adddisplay();

    return rootView;
}



@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

public class Custom_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public Custom_Adapter(Context c) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (recipelist != null) {
            return recipelist.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if (recipelist != null) {
            return recipelist.get(position);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (recipelist != null) {
            return position;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipelist, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txttile = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttile);
            holder.imgrecipe = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgrecipe);
            holder.fav_unfav = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_unfav);
            holder.ratingbar = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
            holder.txtduration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtduration);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        if (recipelist != null) {
            recipeid = recipelist.get(position).getRecipeid();
            checkcounter = db.checkrecipefav(recipeid);
        }

        if (checkcounter > 0) {
            isfav = true;
        } else {
            isfav = false;
        }

        db.close();

        if (isfav) {
            holder.fav_unfav.setImageResource(R.drawable.favourite);
        } else {
            holder.fav_unfav.setImageResource(R.drawable.favourites);
        }

        Typeface face1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "sinkin_sans_300_light.ttf");
        Typeface face2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "sinkin_sans_400_regular.ttf");

        holder.txttile.setTypeface(face2);
        holder.txtduration.setTypeface(face1);


        holder.txttile.setText(recipelist.get(position).getRecipename());

        try {
            String[] prep = recipelist.get(position).getPrep_time().split(" ");
            String[] cook = recipelist.get(position).getCooking_time().split(" ");

            int totalTime = Integer.parseInt(prep[0]) + Integer.parseInt(cook[0]);

            holder.txtduration.setText(""+totalTime+" min");

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String url = DataManager.photourl + "recipe/" + recipelist.get(position).getRecipeid() + ".jpg";

        try {
            url = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
            url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (recipelist.get(position).getVideo_link().equals("none")) {
            //  holder.imgvideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        String rating = recipelist.get(position).getRatings();

        if (rating != null && rating.trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.ratingbar.setRating(Float.valueOf(rating));
        }



        if (holder.imgrecipe != null) {

            if (url != null && url.trim().length() > 0) {
                //final ProgressBar pbar = holder.pbar;
                final ImageView imageView = holder.imgrecipe;
                //final RelativeLayout imgRL = holder.imageRL;

                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, holder.imgrecipe, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                                  View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                        super.onLoadingFailed(imageUri, view, failReason);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
                    }
                });

            } else {
            }

        }


        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txttile, txtduration;
        ImageView imgrecipe;
        ImageView fav_unfav;
        RatingBar ratingbar;
    }
}

public class getrecipe extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    boolean response = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Getting Data...","Please wait....");

        progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progress.setMessage("Please wait....");
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        response = APIManager.getrecipebycusine(DataManager.CUISINE_ID);

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        progress.cancel();
        if (response) {

            if (DataManager.status.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                recipelist = DataManager.recipelist;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),RecipeListActvity.class);

                //startActivity(i);

            } else {

                connectionerror();

            }
        } else {

            connectionerror();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}

public void alert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    alertDialog.setTitle("No Recipe!");

    alertDialog.setMessage("No Recipe for this Cusine");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

    alertDialog.show();
}

private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

    static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        if (loadedImage != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
            if (firstDisplay) {
                FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                displayedImages.add(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void connectionerror() {
    // if (getActivity() == null) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    alertDialog.setTitle("Error!");

    alertDialog.setMessage("Connection Lost ! Try Again");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Retry",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    new getrecipe().execute();

                }
            });

    alertDialog.show();
}

//}}
```

Error:

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
       at com.raccoonfinger.dessert.RecipeListFragment$Custom_Adapter.getView(RecipeListFragment.java:207)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
       at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659)
       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:494)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15614)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4968)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2102)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1859)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5884)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: Are you sure `recipelist ` layout contains TextView with `txttile ` id?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout `recipelist.xml` does not contain `TextView` with id `txttile` or `txtduration`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your problem are because of these

```
    holder.txttile.setTypeface(face2);
    holder.txtduration.setTypeface(face1);
```

You are calling `setTypeface` on null reference. You have to find what is null is this case holder OR txttile OR txtduration OR face1 OR face2.
        Most of the chances is about holder, txttile, txtduration.

Answer (score 0):

in `getView()` you need add three parameter to the method `mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipelist, null);` just like this `mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipelist, parent, false);` it will be working.